# Extract the optimal model based on BIC in R

Tags: r, model

I use the following function in R to choose the model with smallest BIC

```
step(fit4, direction = "both", k=log(nrow(college_train)))
```

In my R markdown profile, every iteration and result appear, which is longer than 4 pages.

I have known that the last one is the model that I want.

Is there a function in R shows only the last model in my R markdown profile when I use `step()`function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure for R markdown but you may try

```
step(fit4, direction = "both", trace = 0, k=log(nrow(college_train)))
```

Comment: it works! @Park So basically, when we use trace = 0, it automatically only shows the optimal model

Comment: @MathildaFang Basically `trace` argument is about details of information if its positive. And if `trace = 0`, only final model will be printed.